# jsSHA HMAC-512 value not match as Node.js HMAC

Tags: node.js, hmac

When using Node.js crypto module

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
    HMACseed = crypto.createHmac('sha512', 'a55e3e55ff89d1cfeab1c85ac4dc7517d8d3228bb41a7d86de9cdf5587126de7').update('02de498327ba9544ba3b5c3d855a56a6761737a399d099b46b2a1d69491ca64ae400000001').digest('hex');
    console.log(HMACseed)
```

result

> 08b87c15c5cc62ebcdb8cf5bf6a61cd168387fcc59db119e19ecd8deb67380dda98dd5faf7409face6ebcb187929176636f593dadbe7d7aa44a1ed59bbe0dff6

But using https://caligatio.github.io/jsSHA/

result

> 6b1312b3706844b11dd50012dd31be8d77f2f7cd9ec0624f730ee24bc4246084cbcaf10f63610cca1b4cc86e8b32a29b6c495a3b8bd28de4d3fd0b98df483530

```
key = 'a55e3e55ff89d1cfeab1c85ac4dc7517d8d3228bb41a7d86de9cdf5587126de7'
data = '02de498327ba9544ba3b5c3d855a56a6761737a399d099b46b2a1d69491ca64ae400000001'
```

I wonder why the jsSHA will result different value of HMAC-256.

Comment: Can you please clarify what your question is?  What do you expect to happen, and why is the thing that is happening "wrong" or problematic?  And what have you tried to do to fix the problem?  Thanks!

Comment: Update the description.

Comment: Node.js result the same as this https://www.freeformatter.com/hmac-generator.html#ad-output but different with jsSHA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to using hex as input or it will regard it as text input.

```
HMACseed = crypto.createHmac('sha512', Buffer.from('a55e3e55ff89d1cfeab1c85ac4dc7517d8d3228bb41a7d86de9cdf5587126de7', 'hex')).update(Buffer.from('02de498327ba9544ba3b5c3d855a56a6761737a399d099b46b2a1d69491ca64ae400000001','hex')).digest('hex');
console.log(HMACseed)
```